# How to add KUBECONFIG secret into the secrets tab?

Tags: github, kubernetes

I am following this [deploying to Kubernetes with Helm](https://medium.com/swlh/deploying-to-kubernetes-with-helm-and-github-actions-14825e6df1f2)
tutorial.

I created AWS EKS cluster.
My cat config shows

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ************************************************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
    server: https://1111D1111B11D4160192088E9F60.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: cwalkerdelimana.us-east-1.eksctl.io
```

Second step says

```
Add a KUBECONFIG secret into the secrets tab
```

What is actually KUBECONFIG secret? certificate-authority-data, yes or no?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
cat $HOME/.kube/config | base64
```